# Is there a common structure for a wordpress formular?

Tags: html, coding-standards

I am working on a plugin for wordpress and was wondering if there is any common standard for the html and css structure and naming which I should use if I create a html form?

so is there a definition how the DOM of a WP form shell look like, and if so: what is the proposed syntax?

sorry for my english ;)

Comment: for admin or for front end?

Comment: for the front end

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommand you to see [this link](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/). This will help you to respect coding standards in WP.

EDIT : add link I give in comments

Comment: actually I can't find nothing about css-naming and forms-structure but thanks anyway.

Comment: ???? [CSS Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/)